# what happens with multiple calls to mouseover and mouseout in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating an experiment which looks at a number of cells with an onclick method.  I am testing to see if making them appear more hyperlink like improves their click through rate.

```
function cursorSelect(element){
    element.css("cursor","pointer");
}
function cursorNormal(element){
    element.css("cursor","default");
}
function colourSelect(element){
    element.css("color","blue");
}
function colourNormal(element){
    element.css("color","black");
}

function variation1(){
    //variation 1 code
    $("td").mouseover(cursorSelect($(this)));
    $("td").mouseout(cursorNormal($(this)));
}

function variation2(){
    //variation 2 code
    $("td").mouseover(colourSelect($(this)));
    $("td").mouseout(colourNormal($(this)));
}

var pageVariations = [
    function() {}, //Original; Mostlikely this will not need changing
    function() {  //Variation 1 goes in here
    variation1();
    },
    function (){ //Variation 2 goes in here
    variation2();
    },
    function (){ //Variation 3 goes in here
    variation1();
    variation2();
    }
    ]
$(document).ready(pageVariations[chosenVariation]);//jQuery launching selected variation
```

What is the behaviour of the jquery mouseover and mouseout settings.  will multiple calls to this method overwrite the settings of the previous call, or append them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will multiple calls to this method overwrite the settings of the previous call, or append them?

All you're doing with that jQuery code is applying CSS, which in JavaScript will add properties to the `element.style` object. As long as you're not applying the same property, they will be merged rather than overridden.

However, you'd be much better off just using CSS to do this. You could easily do something like the following:

```
.variation1 td {
  color: black
}
.variation1 td:hover {
  color: blue;
}

variation2 td {
  cursor: default;
}
.variation2 td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then, based on whichever variation you wanted to show, you'd just add the class `variation1` or `variation2` to a top-level element like `<body>`.

Comment: Absolutely - I plan to alter the stylesheet later.  This is a script driving an A|B experiment to determine, whether I should make the changes I'm thinking of.